# Research in Algebraic Geometry involving Filters.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, filters

In Gillman and Jerrison's book, "Rings of Continuous Functions", they show a nice relationship between the set of z-ideals in C(X) and the set of filters on X.  One can go for with this relationship; for example, proving the smallest measurable cardinal (if any exist) is strongly inaccessible, seems to be better understood from a filter perspective (rather than ideal).

Now instead of considering the spectrum of a ring, is there any usefulness to consider the set of filters (which consist of algebraic sets), and defining a topology on it?  It just seems like some things (like analytic stuff) would be more natural working in a filter setting.

I suppose for a variety V, you could work with something like Filt(V) instead of Spec(V).  Where Filt(V) consists of fixed filters of a certain type (each filter would correspond to a variety).  Is there any study of this kind?  Or is this analogy not very useful?

Comment: Notice, that for a tychonoff space X, the stone-cech compactification of X characterizes the set of ultrafilters on X (i.e. the points of BX are in one-one correspondence with the ultrafilters on X).  This seems like it could be a useful generalization of the spectrum of a ring (at least for the maximal ideals of it).

Comment: filters and ultrafilters are used in real algebraic geometry, which has more connections to logic than the classical one, it seems.

Comment: It seems like I remember seeing something about how the Stone-Cech Compactification characterizes the spectra of a C*-algebra (which generalizes spectrum of ring).  However, this might only be useful (and true) when X satisfies some specific conditions (completely regular).  

Comment: Posted on math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218242

Comment: I apologize if it is considered spam to post the same question on both sites.  I wasn't sure if I should move the question here or not, but I decided to do it anyway since it wasn't getting answered there.  

Comment: six: (1) In the first paragraph of the question, "nonmeasurable" should be "measurable". (2)In your first comment, the canonical bijection between ultrafilters on $X$ and points in its Stone-Cech compactification is only for discrete $X$. In general, the Stone-CEch compactification is a quotient of the space of ultrafilters (and depends on the topology of $X$). (3) I don't see much difference between working with a filter $F$ and working with the ideal of complements of elements of $F$ (except that you might have to move to a different lattice, e.g., open sets vs. closed sets).

Comment: I have corrected the error in the first paragraph. As for the stone-cech, I should clarify: I'm considering maximal filters of zero sets.  You can show that the bijection works then. The point in working with filters, is that it seems like a more natural setting in some instances. If X is completely regular and hausdorff, then I believe the ultrafilters (of zero sets) can be identified with the spectrum of continuous bounded functions on X (where continuous bounded functions on X are supposed to be analogous to regular functions).   

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik Could not you indicate some good in your opinion reference  reflecting the point of view?